# Virtualization in a sandbox software

Tags: virtualization

I need a software to run multiple heavy 3d apps in a virtual environment. It can be a virtual machine or a sandbox.
I had Sandboxie to do this to me but it stopped working, and it seems their support is too bad for them to do something about it. What a shame, bought that for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I use VirtualBox by Oracle. They are doing a great job with keeping up to date with making the software easy to use.  You can even choose how many cores, the amount of RAM, and storage space to allocate to a particular machine.  Make sure to take a snapshot of the machine after all the software is installed.  This helps if an app breaks or glitches out so you can roll back to a fixed version. The download page [below] will allow you to choose your OS and version of the software.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tested it with "multiple heavy 3d apps", a free good Sandboxie alternative is **Shade**

http://www.shadesandbox.com/